# Odoo 14 - account.payment the invoice_ids is removed but what is it replaced with?

Tags: odoo, payment, account

Till Odoo 12, while creating a payment using API calls for invoices, we had to populate the invoice_ids field on the **account.payment** module and it would automatically mark the corresponding invoices PAID once the payment is validated.

I understand there is no functionality loss, however, I don't know what is this functionality replaced with.

I tried using invoice_line_ids and the invoice still doesn't get marked as PAID. There is only 1 move_id and even if I try that the invoice still doesn't get marked as PAID.

any thoughts?

Edit: This is the json that I am trying to send to Odoo to register a payment against an invoice. but the response is :
"The register payment wizard should only be called on account.move or account.move.line records."
I created a separate content after passing args in the json but still the response remained the same.

```
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "method":"call",
  "params":{
    "service": "object",
    "method": "execute",
    "args":[
        "{{databaseName}}",
        {{userId}},
        "{{password}}",
        "account.payment.register",
        "create",
     {
        "can_edit_wizard":true,
        "can_group_payments":false,
        "payment_type":"inbound",
        "partner_type":"customer",
        "source_amount":5.48,
        "source_amount_currency":5.48,
        "source_currency_id":2,
        "partner_id":505449,
        "country_code":"US",
        "journal_id":230,
        "other_journal_id":false,
        "show_other_journal":false,
        "payment_method_id":7,
        "partner_bank_id":false,
        "group_payment":true,
        "amount":5.48,
        "currency_id":2,
        "payment_date":"2022-02-04",
        "communication":"Test Create Invoice 32",
        "payment_difference_handling":"open",
        "writeoff_account_id":false,
        "writeoff_label":"Write-Off",
        "active_model":"account.move",
        "active_id":364660,
        "active_ids":[
           364660
        ]
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Account payment wizard uses [line_ids](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/wizard/account_payment_register.py#L44) field which is supposed to be passed through the context using the `active_ids` key (Odoo will retrieve the account move lines using the active ids)

The [active_model](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/account/wizard/account_payment_register.py#L449) should be passed through the context, if the active model is different from `account.move` or `account.move.line` Odoo will raise the following error:

```
The register payment wizard should only be called on account.move or account.move.line records.
```

The following example will use the same logic used in `Register Payment` button to create and register invoice payment:

```
vals = {}
payment_register_id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'create', [vals], {'context': {'active_model': 'account.move', 'active_ids': invoice_ids}})
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'account.payment.register', 'action_create_payments', [[payment_register_id]])
```

The following values are the default values passed to the create method when we create a payment manually (Using the register payment button on a customer invoice form):

```
{'can_group_payments': False, 'payment_type': 'inbound', 'partner_type': 'customer', 'source_amount': 365125, 'source_amount_currency': 365125, 'source_currency_id': 2, 'company_id': 1, 'partner_id': 10, 'country_code': 'US', 'journal_id': 7, 'payment_method_id': 1, 'payment_token_id': False, 'partner_bank_id': False, 'group_payment': True, 'amount': 365125, 'currency_id': 2, 'payment_date': '2022-02-04', 'communication': 'INV/2021/12/0001', 'payment_difference_handling': 'open', 'writeoff_account_id': False, 'can_edit_wizard': True, 'writeoff_label': 'Write-Off'}
```

***Edit***

You can call the `execute_kw` method and pass context in `kwargs`

```py
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 
 'method': 'call', 
 'params': {
    'service': 'object', 
    'method': 'execute_kw', 
    'args': ('{{databaseName}}', 
              {{userId}}, 
             '{{password}}', 
             'account.payment.register', 
             'create', 
             [{'journal_id': 7, ...}], 
             {'context': {'active_model': 'account.move', 'active_ids': [23]}}
            )
    }, 
    'id': 843350301
}
```

The following code is based on the [JSON-RPC Library](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/backend.html#json-rpc-library) documentation example

```py
import json
import random
import urllib.request

HOST = 
PORT = 
DB = 
USER = 
PASS = 

def json_rpc(url, method, params):
    data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": method,
        "params": params,
        "id": random.randint(0, 1000000000),
    }
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=json.dumps(data).encode(), headers={
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
    })
    reply = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('UTF-8'))
    if reply.get("error"):
        raise Exception(reply["error"])
    return reply["result"]

def call(url, service, method, *args):
    return json_rpc(url, "call", {"service": service, "method": method, "args": args})

# log in the given database
url = "http://%s:%s/jsonrpc" % (HOST, PORT)
uid = call(url, "common", "login", DB, USER, PASS)

args = [{'journal_id': 7}]
kwargs = {'context': {'active_model': 'account.move', 'active_ids': [23]}}

payment_register_id = call(url, "object", "execute_kw", DB, uid, PASS, 'account.payment.register', 'create', args, kwargs)
call(url, "object", "execute", DB, uid, PASS, 'account.payment.register', 'action_create_payments', [payment_register_id])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried adding a context to my json but still no luck. Can you check my edited question and let me know what is wrong with my json?

Comment: You added the `active_model` and `active_ids` to the create values, Odoo expects to find them in the context